# ¿Qué quiere decir "juicioso" en Colombia?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, colombia

Mis amigos colombianos con frecuencia dicen la palabra **juicioso** para definir el comportamiento de alguien.

*Bogotalogo* (ya no disponible vía web) lo define como:

> **juicioso**
>   Obediente. Que se acoge a las reglas y normas sin chistar.

Pero a mí me da la sensación de que a veces también se utiliza más generalmente para indicar que alguien tiene una buena actitud en relación al trabajo o los estudios, o incluso para decir "ocupado":

> —¿Cómo has estado?
>   —Muy bien, **juicioso**.

Entonces, ¿cuál es el significado más o menos exacto de esta palabra en Colombia? Además, ¿se usa en otros países de la región? Porque en España no.

Comment: En realidad no significa "ocupado" pero lo implica. Tal como la respuesta de @SalahAdDin que la persona actúa con prudencia y madurez lo que implica que es una persona que trabaja y/o estudia como es debido, que a su vez implica que se mantiene ocupado en actividades productivas y deja de lado la fiesta, el alcohol y el ocio. Cuando un colombiano contesta "Muy bien, juicioso" quiere decir que no ha ido a "parrandear" recientemente.

Comment: @DGaleano y si nos referimos a un niño pequeño, ¿qué se interpreta de decir que es _juicioso_?

Comment: Ah, claro... también aplica para niños. De manera similar cuando un adulto le recomienda a un menor "portese juicioso" se entiende que desea que el niño se comporte debidamente, obedeciendo y respetando a sus mayores, haciendo sus deberes y tareas, etc. En resumen ejercitando el buen juicio. En realidad en Colombia la definición de "juicioso" es parecida a lo que define la RAE, pero tenemos un término equivalente que no creo que sea tan cercano a su definición. Es usual decirle a un niño "quédese/pórtese formal" donde formal=juicioso.

Comment: Dices que no se usa en España pero yo creo que si, quizá no en el habla coloquial pero yo lo he visto escrito muchas veces: _«era una persona juiciosa»_ y cosas así. No se si el CORDE y el CREA tienen bastante documentación de América para comparar con España pero si buscas _juicioso_ hay más coincidencias en España que en Colombia, en el CORDE 75.9% contra 2.6% y en el CREA 54.8% contra 17.2%

Comment: No se usa en España, efectivamente, en el habla coloquial, pues aquí es una palabra muy formal y en desuso. Es una palabra que podría ser muy típica de tu abuelo, pero que probablemente nunca se la has oído ni a tu padre. Escrita es otro tema, precisamente por que tiene ese aire de formalidad. A parte de eso, por las respuestas que se han dado, el significado es prácticamente idéntico en España y en Colombia.

Comment: La palabra Juicioso en Colombia significa simplemente "portarse bien"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En Colombia, cuando usamos la palabra juicioso, estamos queriendo decir, en el contexto de tu pregunta, que la persona en cuestión ha sido, es, o será educada, aprehensiva, correcta, que no se involucra en problemas, en cosas peligrosas, en pocas palabras:

> [persona] Que muestra buen juicio, prudencia y madurez en sus actos y decisiones.

Adicionalmente, a modo de despedida, la misma frase se usa para hacer entender al interlocutor que el locutor quiere que sea de ese modo, o se porte de ese modo:

> —Hasta luego, hablamos mañana, *juicioso*.

Answer (score 3):

Juicioso en Colombia significa quieto, tranquilo. Asi cuando uno dice "en casa juicioso" significa "en casa tranquilo" ("à la maison tranquille" en francés).

Answer (score 2):

Soy de Colombia y juicioso (a) es una palabra colonial muy comun que significa dedicación. Cuando alquien se despide agregando la palabra juicioso es como decir portate bien.

Comment: Es esto un **comentario** sobre una [respuesta existente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16949/5481)? Dicha respuesta ya incluye "Adicionalmente, a modo de despedida, la misma frase se usa para hacer entender al interlocutor que el locutor quiere que sea de ese modo, o se porte de ese modo: _Hasta luego, hablamos mañana, juicioso._". Si quieres validar una respuesta existente puedes votarla, en lugar de añadir respuestas redundantes que apenas añaden a lo que otras contribuciones ya han aportado.

Answer (score 0):

Me ha parecido muy curioso que en España no exista la palabra juicioso o Juiciosa en el vocabulario coloquial. En colombia utilizamos muchísimo esa palabra.
Como otros lo han dicho aquí, la utilizamos para decir:
-Hola! Cómo estás ?
-Bien juiciosa en la casa.
O en expresiones como.

-Hoy estuve estudiando todo el día
-que juiciosa eres !

-Estoy yendo al gimnasio  juiciosa todos los días.

Comment: ¡Hola! Tu respuesta es similar a otras respuestas anteriores. Si estás de acuerdo con lo que dicen y quieres mostrar tu apoyo, lo mejor es votar esas respuestas y/o dejar un comentario, para evitar tener muchas respuestas iguales. Si lo que quieres es ampliar o mejorar la información o dar otro enfoque, considera [edit]ar tu respuesta para añadir una explicación, decir de qué forma se usa en tu zona, aportar elementos históricos, etc. Más info en [answer].

Answer (score -1):

La defición de [*juicioso*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MbaSLVJ) por la RAE:

> Que procede con cordura o sensatez.

Juicioso es la persona que posee buen juicio, que de nuevo la RAE define como cordura o sensatez.

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish.SE. ¡Cuidado! Si te fijas bien, la pregunta era sobre Colombia (donde al parecer tendría una acepción distinta), y no sobre el castellano en general.