# ¿Qué quiere decir "arrecho" en Venezuela?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, venezuela

Leyendo el reportaje [A Caracas le hace falta un descanso emocional](http://www.eldiario.es/internacional/Caracas-hace-falta-descanso-emocional_0_673332708.html) sobre la capital de Venezuela me topé con este fragmento:

> Franklin, de 48 años, es el vocalista de Arrecho, una banda que adoptó como nombre la que es, si cabe, **la más venezolana de las palabras. Una que sirve –arrecho- para recorrer ambos extremos de ese arco emocional que vive un país en el que una mitad está muy enfadada y la otra bastante satisfecha con lo sucedido los últimos años**. Ahora, su banda cumple seis años sobre los escenarios y tocaba por primera vez sin enchufar, con cuatro guitarras acústicas, un bajo y percusión. "Mi intención, hoy, hacer música y no participar de la marea en la que se ahoga un país de términos secuestrados e histerismo, que se está dejando de lado todo lo que no sea política. "Necesitamos recuperar espacios de calma".

El texto es algo enrevesado, pero básicamente nos está diciendo que arrecho sirve tanto para definir cosas buenas como cosas malas.

Mirando en el Diccionario de americanismos me encuentro con un montón de definiciones. Quitando las que no mencionan a Venezuela sigo encontrando muchas:

> [***arrecho, -a.***](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=arrecho)
>
> I.    1.  adj. Gu, Ho, ES, Ni, Pa, RD, Co; Ve, vulg; Ec, juv. Referido a persona, valiente, animosa.
>   2.  Ho, ES:E, Ni, CR, Co:NE; Ve, vulg; Ch, p.u. Referido a persona, que está de mal genio, furiosa. pop + cult → espon.
>   3.  Gu, Ho, ES, Ni, Ve. Referido a persona, muy trabajadora.
>   5.  CR; Ve, vulg. Referido a persona, que aprovecha las circunstancias para actuar en beneficio propio. pop + cult → espon.
>
> III.  1.  adj. Ni, Pa; Ve, vulg. Referido a cosa, hecho o situación, ardua, muy difícil de hacer. pop + cult → espon.
>
> IV.   1.  adj. Ve. Muy vehemente, intenso y vivo. vulg.
>
> V.    1.  adj. Ve. Referido a cosa, espectacular, sorprendente. vulg.

Por un lado, pues, me parece que la parte de *laborioso* tendría su simil con el [*juicioso* de Colombia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16948/1674). Sin embargo, las otras acepciones abren tal abanico de posibilidades que estoy convencido de que me sería difícil determinar su acepción si la oyera al azar.

Por tanto, ¿cuál es el uso común de *arrecho* en Venezuela? ¿Existen distintas acepciones en función de la zona, el registro u otras variables? ¿Cuál es su origen?

Comment: En Colombia se usa de manera similar aunque se usan más frecuentemente tenaz y berraco de las que hablamos antes [aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17543/11102) con igual significado.

Comment: Yo prefiero usar "temerario" o "imprudente". Dependiendo del caso es intercambiable por la palabra "arrecho". Que nunca me queda claro a que se refiere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como tú mismo dices, la palabra arrecho sirve tanto para cosas malas como para cosas buenas.

En situaciones malas, se usa para cuando una persona está enojada/furiosa o disgustada por la situación que está viviendo en ese momento.

> -Estoy arrecho por que esa persona me robó mi carro y ¡Nadie hace nada!
>
> -Estoy molesto/furioso por que esa persona me robó mi carro y ¡Nadie hace nada!

En situaciones buenas, se usa para describir que algo ha sido fascinante, espectacular o satisfactorio.

> -¡Que concierto arrecho el de ayer!
>
> -¡Que concierto espectacular el de ayer!

Ahora el significado de la oración que pusiste en negrita es que Venezuela está dividida en dos bandos: Los que están molestos por la política actual de su gobierno y los que están convencidos en que su política actual es más que satisfactoria.

Answer (score 1):

En lo que se refiere al origen de la palabra **arrecho**, proviene del latín *erectus* (erguido).
De ahí que en algunos países de Hispanoamérica **arrecho** signifique "excitado", como puede verse en el [Diccionario de americanismos](https://www.asale.org/damer/arrecho):

> II. 1. adj/sust. ES, Ni, Pa, RD, Co, Ec, Pe, Bo. Referido a persona, excitada sexualmente. vulg; pop + cult → espon. ◆ arriola; pindinga.
> 2. adj. Bo, Ch. Referido a persona o animal, que se excita sexualmente con facilidad. vulg; pop + cult → espon.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. Nótese que en la pregunta ya indiqué las acepciones del Damer, pero solamente las referidas a Venezuela, que es la parte que pregunto. En las que incluyes tú no hay ninguna que se refiera al uso que se le da en ese país.

Comment: Yo trataba de responder a la pregunta "¿Cuál es su origen?".