# What does ‘juicio’ mean in Colombia?

Tags: colombia

My colombian friend always says juicio/juicioso/juiciosa when we finish talking to each other and want to say goodbye. Is that one of the way to say goodbye in Colombia?

Comment: I think this question lacks some more context. My first guess is that, when saying goodbye, by using "juicio" one friend tells the other something like: Be good, or Behave yourself.

Comment: I can't find it now, but this was recently discussed in another question.  From memory the consensus was that "juicio" is meant to imply having the behaviors/attributes of a judge - honest, meticulous, straight forward etc.  Hopefully someone else can locate that question.

Comment: If you can read Spanish, [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16948/24236) is the other question where this is discussed.

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thank you so much guys! :)